# Copying XAP file to ClientBin on the deployment server not working

Tags: silverlight, xap, clientbin

All I am trying to do here is that I have a set of files in a network share folder and I am trying to copy them to the deployment server through a PS script.

The .dll and .pdb files are getting copied as expected to the "bin" folder. But the .xap file is not copied to the "ClientBin" folder.

I also tried placing the .dll file into the same folder. That didn't work either. Deleting from the folder also not working.

Here is a snippet from PS script I am using for the deployment.

```
try
    {
    # Copy all of the files from the source location to the deployment directory
    Write-Host "DeployService: Deploying new files for ""$serviceWebSiteName""..."
    Copy-Item $sourceDirectory"\*.dll" $deploymentDirectory
    Copy-Item $sourceDirectory"\*.exe" $deploymentDirectory
    Copy-Item $sourceDirectory"\*.pdb" $deploymentDirectory
    Copy-Item $sourceDirectory"\*.xap" $deploymentDirectory2
    Write-Host "DeployService: Deploying new files for ""$serviceWebSiteName""...complete"
}
catch
{
    Write-Host $_.Exception.ToString() -foregroundcolor red        
}
```

Verified the permissions for the user. The users have same permission on both "bin" folder and the "ClientBin". Not sure how it works for bin and does not for clientbin.

Will greatly appreciate any help or input here

Thanks